# Usage of darker shade to show selected/focused button

Tags: buttons, mobile, color

Consider that I am creating an interface for a mobile app which shows a list of buttons on the main screen. I can move through the buttons using mobile keypad (feature phones) or screen touch (smart phones). I wonder if I should implement the currently focused button in darker shade as compared to the other buttons? Or a lighter shade would work as well? I mean is there any unwritten UX rule that selected/focused button is always in darker color compared to the other buttons on the same screen?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule, written or unwritten. All that matters is that:

1. **The focused state is sufficiently different, yet still clearly the same button.** A change from #EEE to #DDD is usually not enough, but changing a square red button with a border into a blue borderless circle isn't a good idea either.
2. **The focused state is consistent across the interface.** If the focused state of one button is darker, other interface elements on the website, when possible, should follow the same system.

Comment: Yep, it's all about consistency and contrast. If your site is dark, a shift to lighter is a good contrast or vise versa. I would note that buttons that turn darker can look like they've been "pressed" with the right effect though.

Comment: And color is useless in showing a selected item if there are only two things in the list.